# How to efficiently create change variables based on dynamic date differences in R, using incomplete date columns

Tags: r, performance, date, missing-data, dynamic-columns

I have a dataset containing the price and market cap of a stock for a date range. Some dates are missing between the date range. I want to efficiently create new variables that show how much the current price changed from the price x days ago (where x is a list of numbers representing day differences).

For example, I have d1:

```
d1 <- structure(list(Date = c(as.Date("2017-10-28"), as.Date("2017-10-27"), as.Date("2017-10-26"),
                          as.Date("2017-10-24"), as.Date("2017-10-21"), as.Date("2017-10-20")),
                 Price = c(100L, 98L, 102L, 97L, 96L, 100L),
                 MC = c(50L, 55L, 49L, 47L, 50L, 46L)),
            .Names = c("Date", "Price", "MC"))

d1<-as.data.frame(d1)
```

and my desire is to create d2 (assuming I am interested in 1 and 2 day changes):

```
d2 <- structure(list(Date = c(as.Date("2017-10-28"), as.Date("2017-10-27"), as.Date("2017-10-26"),
                          as.Date("2017-10-24"), as.Date("2017-10-21"), as.Date("2017-10-20")),
                Price = c(100L, 98L, 102L, 97L, 96L, 100L),
                MC = c(50L, 55L, 49L, 47L, 50L, 46L),
                Delta1Price = c(0.0204, -0.0392, NA, NA, -0.04, NA),
                Delta1MC = c(-0.0909, 0.12244, NA, NA, 0.0869, NA),
                Delta2Price = c(-0.0196, NA, 0.0515, NA, NA, NA),
                Delta2MC = c(0.0204, NA, 0.04255, NA, NA, NA)),
            .Names = c("Date", "Price", "MC", "Delta1Price", "Delta1MC", "Delta2Price", "Delta2MC"))

d2<-as.data.frame(d2)
```

where the change variables are calculated by (currentValue - previousValue)/PreviousValue

Here is my inefficient way of doing this by using a for-loop:

```
# Assume d1 and d2 are dataframes #
nms <- colnames(d1)[c(2:3)]
changeList <- c(1:2)
for (i in changeList){

    #record the dates that will be used to calculate changes
    currentDate <- d1$Date
    revDate <- currentDate-i

    #filter out the rows for the older relevant date
    revData <- d1 %>% 
        dplyr::filter(d1$Date %in% revDate)

    #Get the newer dates that are available
    newCurDate <- revData$Date+i
    newCurData <- d1 %>%
    dplyr::filter(d1$Date %in% newCurDate)

    #calculate the change variables
    changes <- (newCurData[, nms] - revData[,nms])/revData[,nms]

    #dynamically name these new change variables
    newCurData[, paste("Delta", paste(i, nms, sep=""), sep="")]<- changes

    #merge the data to get desired outcome
    d1 <- merge(d1, newCurData, all=TRUE)
}
#final output should be the same d2 that I structured
d2 <- d1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should avoid loops in R. Not that they are bad *per se* but most of functions accept vectors and are optimised for it, in a way you would probably not reach with naive loops. And things get usually much easier to read without loops.

Secondly, if you work with vectors, some powerful packages have a "lag" method. It is called `lag(...)` in `dplyr` so that `(values - lag(values))/lag(values)` will do most of the work ; it is called `shift(..., n=1)` in `data.table`.

Thirdly, you may take advantage of `data.table`'s [rolling joins](https://gormanalysis.com/r-data-table-rolling-joins), which are generally explained with date-matching. (This feature is not yet implemented in `dplyr`, see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2240).) Do I correctly understand that you are doing a self-join? Then you should explicitly join data sets: `d1 %>% left_join(d1)` with `dplyr` or `d1[d1]` in `data.table`.

Lastly, why don't you use packages dedicated to your task? Computing returns for financial assets seems so commun that I doubt you are the only one facing the issue. You may have more chance on the task-pages for [finance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html) and [time-series](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

---

I wrap it up.

```
library(datat.table)
d1 <- data.table(
   Date = as.Date(c("2017-10-28", "2017-10-27", "2017-10-26", "2017-10-24", "2017-10-21", "2017-10-20")),
   Price = c(100L, 98L, 102L, 97L, 96L, 100L)
)
d1[,Date2:=Date] # duplicates the time column, see after
```

This solves the problem I understood:

```
d1[
   d1,
   list(
     Date,  Previous_date=Date2, Gap=Date-Date2,
     Price, Previous_price=i.Price,
     Return=(Price-i.Price)/i.Price
   ),
   on="Date<Date2",
   mult='first'
]
```

Here the explanation: `d1[d1]` is a classical merge with the `data.table` package. There is many way to specify which columns to use for the merge, but here I use `on`, that specifies on-th-fly merging columns. From `v1.9.8` it is possible to use inequalities for the merge! Here we go: `on="Date<Date2"`. Note that the left-side refers to the first `d1` (before the brackets), and the right-side to the second (inside the brackets).

But doing so, we get a **lot** of matches (all the previous observations are matched), and we are interested only in the most recent one, hence `mult='first'`. Note that for this to work, the data set has to be ordered according to time.

Last but not least, we can do the computation on the fly. All what we want to get in the output has to be put inside a `list()` instruction. We can use the `i.` prefix to refer to the `d1` from inside the brackets, such as in `Previous_price=i.Price`. Unfortunately, this does not work on the variables used for merging (`Date` here) so that `i.Date` gives the same result as `Date`. This is probably a bug, but in the meanwhile, I copied the `Date` column before hands, under the name `Date2`, that we can use for instance in `Gap=Date-Date2`.

---

I must say I do not especially like the esoteric `data.table` syntax. But here, `dplyr` lags behind. This should be covered soon, however, [it seems](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2240).

Comment: Thanks for the tips Arthur. I will check out the task-page on finance and time-series. I only did a self-join to illustrate my problem, but not sure if that is the most efficient way to do it. In terms of the lag method, I looked into some posts about it before, but it seems to work well if the time-series is consistently spaced. In my case, I have inconsistent time-series data due to some missing dates in between.

Comment: Edited my answer. I admit it wasn't that simple... :D